Can IWYU be told to ignore headers altogether?
IWYU (include-what-you-use) normally demands that you directly include every header that exports every symbol that you are using. This is fine for your own project's headers and is actually the state you want to achieve. But for STL headers, you don't want to do this, as you easily run into cases where you depend on version- or platform specific details. I have run into the problem where I am using std::string's operator[]. This operator needs struct __alloc_traits, which happens to be declared in ext/alloc_traits.h, and so it tells me I have to include this header. But the documented way to get it is by including <string>, which I'm already doing. I have searched far and wide, and there appears that IWYU offers only two remedies for this:

Pragmas. But this means that every time I use std::strings indexing operator, I'd have to pepper the code with a pragma comment.

Mappings. This means that every time IWYU would tell me to include a certain header, it should replace this header with another one. The thing is, ext/alloc_traits is included by dozens of headers, unordered_map, list and tree being among them. The mapping can't know which of these I'm already including. There is no documented way to create a mapping to an empty list of includes.


I tried the above approaches. Pragmas are unpractical because of the clutter. It will invariably just become a stumbling block and I can't motivate my team to use IWYU with such gotchas. Mappings are inflexible and ultimately solve a different problem. My only resort is to wrap IWYU in another script that filters out the poor suggestions, but that comes with a maintenance burden.

I found a non-documented way to fix this, actually. You can specify several mappings, and iwyu is clever enough to find out which one you should use. In this case, I created two mappings:
mappings.imp
[
 {"include" : [ "<ext/alloc_traits.h>", "private", "<unordered_map>", "public" ]},
 {"include" : [ "<ext/alloc_traits.h>", "private", "<string_view>", "public" ]},
]

Since it's not documented, I didn't know if this would cause iwyu to tell me to always include both <unordered_map> and <string>, but it turns out to be smart enough to understand that as long as I include one of them, I'm good to go and it doesn't complain about the file.
I conducted the following experiment to verify that it works:
main.cpp:
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

void foo() {
  std::vector<std::string_view> v;
  v[0] = std::string_view("abc", 1);
}

Compilation command:
$ iwyu --version
include-what-you-use 0.17 based on Ubuntu clang version 13.0.1-2ubuntu2.2
$ clang++-13 --version
Ubuntu clang version 13.0.1-2ubuntu2.2
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
$ CXX=clang++-13 iwyu -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -std=gnu++2a -c main.cpp 

main.cpp should add these lines:
#include <ext/alloc_traits.h>  // for __alloc_traits<>::value_type

main.cpp should remove these lines:

The full include-list for main.cpp:
#include <ext/alloc_traits.h>  // for __alloc_traits<>::value_type
#include <string_view>         // for string_view
#include <vector>              // for vector
---

If I add -Xiwyu --mapping_file=mappings.imp to the compilation command, it accepts main.cpp.
Then, I created another program:
main_um.cpp:
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

void fie() {
  std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, int>> v;
  v[0] = {};
}

Here, too, I get complaints about ext/alloc_traits.h:
$ CXX=clang++-13 iwyu -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -std=gnu++2a -c main_om.cpp -Xiwyu
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Xiwyu'

main_om.cpp should add these lines:
#include <ext/alloc_traits.h>  // for __alloc_traits<>::value_type

main_om.cpp should remove these lines:

The full include-list for main_om.cpp:
#include <ext/alloc_traits.h>  // for __alloc_traits<>::value_type
#include <unordered_map>       // for unordered_map
#include <vector>              // for vector
---


But adding the same -Xiwyu --mapping_file=mappings.imp causes it to pass.
